# sudo and --ask-sudo-pass on CentOS 6.6

Tags: centos, centos6, sudo, ansible

I'm running command:

```
[kamil@server.com ]# ansible example.com -a "sudo id" --ask-sudo-pass
sudo password:
example.com | FAILED >> {
"failed": true,
"msg": "[sudo] password for kamil: \r\n{\"changed\": true, \"end\": \"2015-02-05 12:06:16.612869\", \"stdout\": \"\", \"cmd\": [\"sudo\", \"id\"], \"start\": \"2015-02-05 12:01:16.533325\", \"delta\": \"0:05:00.079544\", \"stderr\": \"\", \"rc\": 1, \"warnings\": []}\r\nOpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_forwards: requesting forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 21782\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 3\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 3\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\nShared connection to example.com closed.\r\n",
"parsed": false
}
```

The same command running against for example Debian is working.

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
ansible example -a "id" --sudo -K
```

This runs the command using ansible's built in sudo function which will utilize the -K (ask-sudo-pass) flag. If you try to run sudo within the command, it will not use the -K (--ask-sudo-pass) password.

Comment: Please expand upon your answer and how it differs from the questioner's example.

Comment: Yes, this is working, but why -a "sudo id" is not working on CentOS byt on Debian is running well. Maybe this is a bug in ansible?

Comment: If you add the use as a no password user in sudoer that would work, but due to the nature of ansible you must make the command run with the sudo flag and -Kv